# Is there a shortcut for 'go to method parameters'?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there any way to jump to the method parameters from any point inside of this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the cursor on a parameter name within the method and press the following key combination.

On OSX:  <kbd>cmd</kbd> +<kbd>b</kbd>

On Windows: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd>

Comment: Nope, that's for navigating to method declaration from outside (the place where it used). My question is different: you're inside of method body, how do you jump to it's own declaration (params/method name)?

Comment: Try it, click on a param name within the body of the method and it will jump up to its declaration.

Comment: You're right, probably it's the closest one to what I need. Has to be performed on param tho, otherwise 'Cannot find declaration to go to'. Would you be so kind to complement your answer? I mean, I'm using Ctrl+B for years and it wasn't obvious for me.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Navigate Between Methods and Tags](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/navigating-between-methods-and-tags.html) and while with the cursor in the function:

On OSX: <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>

On Windows: <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>

which will move you to the next method header upwards — actually the current method — and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> or <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to your parameters. No mouse / parameter usage lookup needed